# Is "huh" a question tag? Is it a universal tag?

Tags: tag-questions

According to Oxford dictionary, huh is an exclamation. One of the definitions said:

> people use Huh? at the end of     questions, suggestions, etc.,
> especially when they want somebody to agree with them.
> Examples:

1. So you won't be coming tonight, huh? (I'm assuming it replaced **will you**)
2. Let's get out of here, huh? (I'm assuming it replaced **shall we**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption of replacement words is  over simplifying things a little but if it helps you understand, then yes your statements are somewhat correct.

---

**Note** UK also use eh!

used at the end of a question or statement, especially when **you want someone to agree with what you have said:**

*Simple use*

I'll bet you wish you hadn't done that, huh?

Pretty cool, huh?

---

*A more complex use;*

This is very difficult to explain however I will try to set the scene and show one of the uses

*Couple sitting at home watching TV*.

Husband: *Let's go for a pint.*

*No immediate reaction from wife (very short time).*

Husband:  *Huh!*

---

An alternative use is quite well defined By the Cambridge English Dictionary.

huh! exclamation (UK)  informal; Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/huh)

**used to show that you have not heard or understood something:**

Examples

> "So what do you want to do tonight?" "Huh? What did you say?"

> Huh? These instructions don't make sense!

**used to express disapproval:**

> Huh, I don't think much of that idea!